# Flutter: Difference of size between ios and android

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I have an issue with my flutter app.

I use 2 physical devices

Android: A20
Iphone: Iphone 11

I setup fontsize but the font size on the iPhone is not fulfilled.

Please find below: the screens from both devices.

How can I fix this difference?

[image: IPhone 11]

IPhone 11

[image: Android]

Android

Material app

```
GetMaterialApp(
      title: L.localize('Wetip'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch:
            PaletteGenerator.generateMaterialColor(MyTheme.PrimaryColor),
        primaryColor: MyTheme.PrimaryColor,
        accentColor: MyTheme.SecondaryColor,
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.ralewayTextTheme(),
        disabledColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
        errorColor: MyTheme.PrimaryColor,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity
      ),
      home: MyApp())
```

The textformfield

```
 TextFormField(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 16,
        color: colorText != null ? colorText : Colors.black,
        decorationColor: Colors.black),
```

Et mon titleSection

```
Widget TitleSection(String text, {color = Colors.white, TextStyle?
```

style}) {
return Text(
text,
textAlign: TextAlign.center,
style: style == null
? TextStyle(
color: color,
fontSize: Theme.of(navigatorKey.currentContext!)
.textTheme
.headline4!
.fontSize)
: style,
);
}

Comment: can you check the iOS device's default text size?

Comment: Ok I have been able to fix this by changing text size in settings. But it's not a solution. How can I ensure I will have the same text size between ios and and android? And I would say it's more a scaling than a font size

Comment: Can you add some code of how you set text and its property for the attached screenshot?

Comment: I added some code

Answer (score 1):

I prefer [Sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) Package for auto scaling of fonts

First you have to wrap materialApp with Responsive Sizer widget

```
ResponsiveSizer(
      builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
        return MaterialApp();
      }
 )
```

Then you can use font size like below

```
    Text(
      'Sizer',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.sp),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This was explained in the [GoogleIO presentation](https://youtu.be/YSULAJf6R6M?t=1230) you can try their solution.

```
MaterialApp(
      builder: (context, child) {
        return MediaQuery(
          child: child,
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
        );
      },
)
```

Setting the `MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context)` should also help

eg.  `fontSize: 18 * MediaQuery.textScaleFactorOf(context),`

Comment: Ok thanks. Is it a normal behaviour? Or I missed something in my development?

I mean if I put textscalefactor to 1 if the user increase the text size it will not be changed. 

So the final solution should be to multiply my font sizes by the text factor?

Comment: Yes, that's how accessibility/pixel density settings works across device  AFAIK https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/accessibility

Comment: But I don't get it. the picture I show in my first message is the default scaling provided in the iPhone. There is no special accessibility settings setup.

Comment: just a guess, your A20 had less pixel ratio compared to your iphone 11, can you check visiting different website/apps on both the phones and check

Comment: The A20 has 268 pixels per inch and the iphone 11 has 458 PPI. It's a big difference. Then how can I setup my project to have the same scale?

Comment: using textScaleFactor doesn't help ?  something like  scaleFactor = MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;... and in    fontSize: 14 / scaleFactor ?